# Adding adMob to already existing Firebase application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, admob

The title may be confusing for you, but I'll give it a try to explain as good as possible in here.

I've an application which are using Firebase Firestore as a storage. I've now decided to add AdMob into my project, but this will end up in two  "GoogleService-Info.plist" files. And my question is which one to remove/replace? I cannot run the program because I get the error:

> :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.app/GoogleService-Info.plist':
>   1) Target 'MyDogwalk' (project 'MyDogwalk') has copy command from '/Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk/MyDogwalk/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
>   2) Target 'MyDogwalk' (project 'MyDogwalk') has copy command from '/Users/puttemac/Desktop/MyDogwalk-ios/MyDogwalk/MyDogwalk/New Group/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/puttemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyDogwalk-eiogfpjopcpzxaalyodbyllsajwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyDogwalk.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'

I need to keep my Firestore and I also want to add "AdMob" to my project, but how can I do that?

At the moment I've two "GoogleService-Info.plist"

[image: img]

Anyone of you has done this before? I've two .plist files, but it seems like I can only have one. How can I do this? How can I have Firestore and AdMob at the same project? All help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need 2 `GoogleService-Info.plist` if you have two different targets in the project and two deferent FireBase project/Apps.

Make sure

- You have the same Firebase project (compare the `CLIENT_ID`)
- That the new `GoogleService-Info.plist` has all the items from the old one (if not add them manually)
- Use the second one as it would probably have all the items

Comment: So, I can add the new GoogleService-Info.plist and it would contain the old ones? And if not, I’ll add them manually? :) Thanks for the answer